# Group some strings of a list by every x index occurance

Tags: c#, linq

```
var strings = new List<string> 
{ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p" };

int rotation = 4; // could also be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 but 4 is for the sample
```

I want to query the strings list and return a grouped list of anonym type which holds this data:

```
group0: a,b,c,d,i,j,k,l
group1: d,e,f,g,m,n,o,p
```

if the **rotation** is **2** that would be another sample:

```
group0: a,b,e,f,i,j,m,n
group1: c,d,g,h,k,l,o,p
```

Somehow I have to check each string and its index position, find a clever algo and combine that with the rotation of 4 for example.

Comment: Did you tried _anything_?

Comment: of course many things like:  var query = strings.Where((s, index) => (index/rotation)%rotation == 1).ToList(); OR  var query = strings.Where((s, index) => (index/rotation)%rotation == 0).ToList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
var group0 = strings.Where((s, i) => (i/rotation)%2 == 0).ToArray();
var group1 = strings.Where((s, i) => (i / rotation) % 2 == 1).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks I have its the modulo by 2             var query = strings.Select((s, index) => new { Group = (index / rotation) % 2, Name = s }).ToList();

Answer (score 2):

Use the version of Select accepting an index parameter. Then take the mod (%) operator and see if the resulting number is even or odd. (index % size% 2 == 0).

You can Select either a tuple or an anonymous type with the value and whether it is even/odd. Then GroupBy using the even/odd as the group key and the value as the group value.

```
values.Select ((value, index) => 
    new 
    {
        Value = value,
        First = index % size % 2 == 0
    }
).GroupBy(pair => pair.First, pair => pair.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var strings = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p" };
int rotation = 2;

int inx = 0;
var groups = strings.GroupBy(s => (inx++ / rotation)%2)
                    .Select(g => g.ToList())
                    .ToList();
```